# Angular 2 router navigation doesn't work

Tags: node.js, angular, routes

Please check onSignIn() method in the end of the file

https://github.com/haykaghabekyan/angular2/blob/master/client/app/signin/signin.component.ts

The problem is that it is not navigating to the url I need after the user is being successfully authenticated.

I think it can happen because of the Observable object..
Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually navigates you, but AuthGuard that you've use in your route navigates back to sign-in.

Comment: I have removed authService provider from my component and that helps